# Is this a valid loop?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have the following code:

```
private ScatterViewItem FindScatterViewOfSourceFile(SourceFile find)
{
   foreach (ScatterViewItem svi in classScatterViews)
   {
      if ((svi.Tag as SourceFile).Equals(find))
      {
         return svi;
      }
   }
   return null;
}
```

Now I'm asking myself if this is valid or if I should better use:

```
private ScatterViewItem FindScatterViewOfSourceFile(SourceFile find)
{
   ScatterViewItem result = null;
   foreach (ScatterViewItem svi in classScatterViews)
   {
      if ((svi.Tag as SourceFile).Equals(find))
      {
         result = svi;
         break;
      }
   }
   return result;
}
```

Is there any common practive which one to use? And are both loops doing the same?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First one is hundred times better then the second one. I would avoid defining a variable if you don't really need to. Also I don't believe in `one return` methods. Especially I don't believe that they improve readability.

LINQ would definitely improve it:

```
return classScatterViews.FirstOrDefault(v => v.Tag.Equals(find));
```

Also I would not use `as` operator if I do not check result for `null`.

Answer (score 9):

So you have heard about the good practice that a method should only have one return statement.
This is generally true, but in your case I find it not to be necessary because the method is so small. The main reason for this 'rule' is readability, so you know what is going on. Both code samples are equally clear. When you have several places where a `return` would occur, it's best to use the second approach.

However, I would rewrite it by using LINQ. I believe this should work:

```
private ScatterViewItem FindScatterViewOfSourceFile(SourceFile find)
{
    return classScatterViews.FirstOrDefault( svi => svi.Tag.Equals(find) );
}
```

UPDATE:

Also note that the cast to the specific type to call the `Equals()` is dropped. This is redundant as the correct Equals() will be called anyhow.

Comment: [nitpick] It will be called *only* if `ScatterViewItems` implemented in obvious way

Comment: @Snowbear: I can't think of the nonobvious way right now, perhaps I'm missing something. :O Enlighten me. ;p

Comment: `public new bool Equals(object other)` in `SourceFile` ;-)

Comment: Ugh!, ... thanks for me reminding me why I never use `new`. ;p

Comment: Exactly, though I believe on `code review` site we should discuss only your version because such `new Equals` will never pass good review.

Comment: @Snowbear: Just update your answer accordingly. ;p

Comment: "The main reason for this 'rule' is readability, so you know what is going on." That's simply not true. This rule was created for languages like C that don't automatically manage resources. Returning early from a function that may have allocated early makes it too easy to forget to deallocate it. In a GC language like C#, there's no need for this rule.

Comment: @munificent: Agreed, most likely that rule lessens readability as it forces a lot of nesting.

Comment: @munificent: Thanks for the history lesson, I didn't know that. However, I can give you examples where multiple return statements ARE less readable. Also the fact that there are other reasons doesn't exclude the fact that it also is a practice known to improve readability. I'll rephrase, the [only reason I knew of](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36707/should-a-function-have-only-one-return-statement). ;p